# Problem using related entities in "database-first"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am learning MVC and for do this I am developing a "smart forum". I have do a database but I have some problem with entities. I have do this command

```
 "Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=SmartForum;Trusted_Connection=True; Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir ModelsFromDb" ,
```

A code snippet:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ArgomentiPerArea>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.ArgomentoId);

                entity.Property(e => e.ArgomentoId).HasColumnName("argomentoId");

                entity.Property(e => e.Archiviato).HasColumnName("archiviato");

                entity.Property(e => e.AreaId).HasColumnName("areaId");

                entity.Property(e => e.ModeratoreId).HasColumnName("moderatoreId");

                entity.Property(e => e.NomeArgomento).HasColumnName("nome_argomento");

                entity.Property(e => e.NumeroRigaPerArea).HasColumnName("numero_riga_per_area");

                entity.Property(e => e.TestoPerArgomento).HasColumnName("testo_per_argomento");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Area)
                    .WithMany(p => p.ArgomentiPerArea)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.AreaId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_ArgomentiPerArea_Aree");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Moderatore)
                    .WithMany(p => p.ArgomentiPerArea)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ModeratoreId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_ArgomentiPerArea_Moderatori");
            });
```

a second snippet :

```
public partial class ArgomentiPerArea
    {
        public ArgomentiPerArea()
        {
            Thread = new HashSet<Thread>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int ArgomentoId { get; set; }
        public string NomeArgomento { get; set; }
        public int? AreaId { get; set; }
        public bool? Archiviato { get; set; }
        public int? NumeroRigaPerArea { get; set; }
        public string TestoPerArgomento { get; set; }
        public int? ModeratoreId { get; set; }

        public virtual Aree Area { get; set; }
        public virtual Moderatori Moderatore { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Thread> Thread { get; set; }

    }

public partial class Aree
    {
        public Aree()
        {
            ArgomentiPerArea = new HashSet<ArgomentiPerArea>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int AreaId { get; set; }
        public string NomeArea { get; set; }
        public int? NumeroRiga { get; set; }
        public int? NumeroColonna { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArgomentiPerArea> ArgomentiPerArea { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Moderatori
    {
        public Moderatori()
        {
            ArgomentiPerArea = new HashSet<ArgomentiPerArea>();
            SegnalazioniPerModeratori = new HashSet<SegnalazioniPerModeratori>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int ModeratoreId { get; set; }
        public string UsernameModeratore { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string NomeCognome { get; set; }
        public bool? Archiviato { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArgomentiPerArea> ArgomentiPerArea { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SegnalazioniPerModeratori> SegnalazioniPerModeratori { get; set; }
    }
```

when this code run

```
public class ArgomentiPerAreasController : Controller
    {
        private ModelsFromDb.SmartForumContext db = new ModelsFromDb.SmartForumContext();

        // GET: ArgomentiPerAreas
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var argomentiPerAreas = db.ArgomentiPerArea.Include(a => a.Area).Include(a => a.Moderatore);            

            string msg = "m";
            return View(argomentiPerAreas.ToList());
        }

.............
.............}
```

I check in view and "moderatore" and "area" have null value.
 I don't understand but I know database first and MVC superficially. I hope in some suggestions.

Comment: asp.net-mvc has nothing to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: data are returned to view

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to circular references between your Argomenti* & the Moderator/Area. An Area holds a collection back to the Argomenti* so when MVC goes to serialize the root entity (Argomenti) it comes across the Area, then iterating through the area, a collection of Argomenti*, and co the cycle goes. It bails out and doesn't attempt to serialize the cyclical dependencies.

Generally the best thing to do with EF and views is *not* to attempt to send entities to the view. Instead, create a POCO (Plain old C# object) View Model to send to the view. This view model contains only the fields needed by the view, and your EF query uses `.Select()` to populate that view model.  This avoids the whole cyclic reference issue, and negates the need for deliberate eager loading (`.Include()`) or the performance risk of lazy loading.

For example: If I want a list of Argumenti, and I want to display each Area and Moderator as part of that:

```
[Serializable]
public class ArgumentiViewModel
{
    public string NomeArgomento { get; set; }
    public bool? Archiviato { get; set; }
    public int? NumeroRigaPerArea { get; set; }
    public string TestoPerArgomento { get; set; }
    public string NomeArea { get; set; } // From Area
    public string NomeCognome { get; set; } // From Moderator
}
```

Then when I want to return this to the view:

```
var argomentiViewModels = db.ArgomentiPerArea
    .Select(x => new ArgomentiViewModel
    {
        NomeArgomento = x.NomeArgomento,
        Archiviato - x.Archiviato,
        NumeroRigaPerArea = x.NumeroRigaPerArea,
        TestoPerArgomento = x.TestoPerArgomento,
        NomeArea = x.Area.NomeArea, // From Area
        NomeCognome = x.Moderatori.NomeCognome // From Moderator
    }).ToList();

string msg = "m";
return View(argomentiViewModels);
```

I sumarized a couple good reasons why code should not return Entities to the view [here](https://py-sty.blogspot.com/2018/12/2-very-good-reasons-why-you-should.html).